# Mesh is almost entirely black in rendered mode

Tags: mesh, uv

I am currently trying to set up a character that I ripped from a game, which until now has been relatively painfree.

However after placing the textures and uv mapping it has become apparent that the character is basically just black in rendered, and I just can't find a way to fix it.[image: Object view]

[image: Rendered view]

Here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rxh4i6zhr05x691/9S.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is quite a mess.

Your **sunlight doesn't seems to be emitting** any light - Create a native Cycles Sun or give the current one a proper shader node tree.

Your **model is full of custom normals** which are known to cause shading trouble - [Clear your custom normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57006/problem-when-importing-obj-to-blender/57022#57022)

Some textures seem to not be picking up **proper UV channel** - Add an explicit Texture Coordinate node with UV coordinates to your textures.

Most of your geometry seems to have **Inverted Normals** - [Recalculate normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92761/its-dangerous-to-flip-a-mesh-with-s-x-y-z-1/92762#92762) and make sure they are pointing outwards