# Cycles render Blender 2.79b - Texture/Material being rendered solid black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, uv

EDIT: So after restarting my pc, and messing around with options I got the texture to show up but it was still broken ( as if it was deepfried ). I retried with a new project and started out with blender render which worked fine, I then switched back to cycles, reapplied the texture and it works fine now. I don't know how but I won't complain.

I am still a beginner with Blender. I imported a csgo model along with it's texture. After I applied the texture, it's visible in texture/material mode but renders completely black when I preview render. Any help is appreciated.

[Dropbox - .blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7y8c2uu0uyd4zi/blender_help.blend?dl=1)

[Dropbox - .tga (texture file if missing)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dc8l9eengf7ymfi/m4a4.tga?dl=1)

[image]

[image]

Comment: "downloaded model", mmm... most likely duplicate: [strange black shading, cannot fully light model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles) or [object appears black](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120675/object-appears-black-while-rendering-while-other-objects-look-normal/120677#120677) or [mesh is entirely black](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95867/mesh-is-almost-entirely-black-in-rendered-mode/95869#95869)

Comment: Micle, I've tested your file and Cegaton is right, you need to click this button

Answer (score 0):

So after restarting my pc, and messing around with options I got the texture to show up but it was still broken ( as if it was deepfried ). I retried with a new project and started out with blender render which worked fine, I then switched back to cycles, reapplied the texture and it works fine now. I don't know how but I won't complain.