# Cycles renders material black in blender 3.3

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, uv

I've used BlenderGis to import shapefile geometry.

Rendered in Cycles, most of them appear black.
The old [Cycles render Blender 2.79b - Texture/Material being rendered solid black](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132798/cycles-render-blender-2-79b-texture-material-being-rendered-solid-black) recommends to clear the custom normals, but there don't seem to be any available in the first place.

Here's the blend file:
[image]

The only thing that has helped to show the object at all was to increase emission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overlappings objects, it will appear black in Cycles (it's called *Z fighting*), remove the useless objects:

[image]

Comment: fantastic, thank you so much!